# Как сделать регистрацию в wordpress с любым логином (генерировать уникальное имя до регистрации)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, регистрация

**Задач такая:**
До регистрации изменить логин на уникальный чтобы пользователь никогда не получал ошибки что такое имя пользователя уже есть

**Попытки:**
У меня есть 2 функции одна транслитерацию делает вторая генерирует уникальное имя
с функциями нет проблем а вот где перехватить логин не знаю пробовал на этот фильтр вешаться:

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'filter_function_name_4366' );
function filter_function_name_4366( $user_login ){
    // filter...

    return $user_login;
}
```

Но как оказалось "pre_user_login" не вызывается на странице *(поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь)*:
wp-login.php?action=register

Пишу сразу ответ так как пока писал вопрос додумался до него, может кому пригодиться...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ОТВЕТ (Если у кого то есть решения получше предлагайте, спасибо!):**

*Логин на странице регистрации передается POST из формы, я просто написал перехват вверху своего functions.php и перезаписал переменную применив к ней 2 функции транслитерации и генерации уникального имени*

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'registerLoginUnique', 1);

function registerLoginUnique(){
   if($_GET['action'] == 'register'){//Убедимся что мы на странице регистрации
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) && is_string( $_POST['user_login'] ) ) {
    // функция генерации уникального имени пользователя
        function generate_unique_username( $username ) {
            $username = sanitize_title( $username );
            static $i;
            if ( null === $i ){
                $i = 1;
            } else {
                $i++;
            }
            if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) {
                return $username;
            }
            $new_username = sprintf( '%s%s', $username, $i );
            if ( ! username_exists( $new_username ) ) {
                return $new_username;
            } else {
                return call_user_func( __FUNCTION__, $username );
            }
        }

        // Транслитератор
        function translit($s) {
        $s = (string) $s; // преобразуем в строковое значение
        $s = strip_tags($s); // убираем HTML-теги
        $s = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), " ", $s); // убираем перевод каретки
        $s = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $s); // удаляем повторяющие пробелы
        $s = trim($s); // убираем пробелы в начале и конце строки
        $s = function_exists('mb_strtolower') ? mb_strtolower($s) : strtolower($s); // переводим строку в нижний регистр (иногда надо задать локаль)
        $s = strtr($s, array('а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'g','д'=>'d','е'=>'e','ё'=>'e','ж'=>'j','з'=>'z','и'=>'i','й'=>'y','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n','о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t','у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'h','ц'=>'c','ч'=>'ch','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shch','ы'=>'y','э'=>'e','ю'=>'yu','я'=>'ya','ъ'=>'','ь'=>''));
        $s = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z-_ ]/i", "", $s); // очищаем строку от недопустимых символов
        $s = str_replace(" ", "", $s); // заменяем пробелы на пустоту (удаляем их)
        return $s; // возвращаем результат
        }

        $_POST['user_login'] = generate_unique_username(translit($_POST['user_login']));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно и так, но такие вещи надо вешать на хук `init`.

Comment: Без проблем, отредактировал ответ, если есть еще какие то замечания/предложения поправлю код.

Comment: В данном случае должно работать на `login_init` - я не тестировал, просто посмотрел код `wp-login.php`

Comment: Могу сказать что оно работает "login_init" и пожалуй хорошо что инициализируется только на странице wp-login.php, благодарю.